# Multiple threads on one page using ajax FOSCommentBundle form and Symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony, foscommentbundle

What is the best way to place more than one thread on a page while using the FOSCommentBundle? It seems that this is not supported by default with the ajax method of including comments on a page. Should I try to avoid the ajax method or is there an easy way to get multiple threads on a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is talk about loading multiple threads asynchronously on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/pull/235), but it is not supported natively yet. What you can easily do for now is to load the thread from your controller, see [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/10-other_ways_of_adding_comments_to_a_page.md).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is something that needs to be implemented by working directly with the REST api. I am going to give that a go.